# DB2 getting top 10 rows from all the tables within a database

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a database `TestDB`, how can I get the top x number of rows from the all the tables from this database?

Comment: You need to generate a SELECT for each table.

Comment: What kind of result set are you looking for ?

Comment: You may generate the corresponding statements to execute them later with a select statement on the [SYSCAT.TABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html) system catalog view.

Comment: I've always wondered what the top ten lookup codes were in most systems?  M - Male?

Comment: "Top ten" necessarily means you will need to order results from each table, and ordering criteria will presumably be different for all/most tables.